# ffmpeg: speed up AND rotate video

Tags: ffmpeg

This is my current script that I'm trying to use to speed up the playspeed and rotate my video by 90', but it doesn't work when I include the `transpose=1` argument.

```
"C:\ffmpeg-win64\bin\ffmpeg.exe" -i "C:\video1.mkv" -vf "setpts=PTS/60" "transpose=1" -an -crf 18 "C:\video2.mkv"
```

Script works without the transpose argument and speeds up my video perfectly, but Script won't run once I try to rotate the video by 90' and outputs an error:

```
Unable to find a suitable output format for 'transpose=1'
transpose=1: Invalid argument
```

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combined command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -vf "setpts=PTS/60,transpose=1" -an -crf 18 output.mkv
```

Simple filters (filters that accept 1 input and make 1 output) can be connected with a comma. See [FFmpeg Filtering Documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html).